# I can't retrieve correct output to a dict in python

Tags: python

please see this code. For the dic[0] it must be printed 'med' and not 'No'. How to fix this issue, please?

```
dico = {}

listo = ['med', 'lam', 'rih', 'holy', 'lem']
mm = ['med', 'holy']
for i, v in enumerate(listo):
    for x in mm:
        if x in v:
            dico[i] = x
        else:
            dico[i] = 'No'
            
dico
```

this is the output:

`{0: 'No', 1: 'No', 2: 'No', 3: 'holy', 4: 'No'}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you set the value in the dict to `x` if there is a match, but then continue the loop and set it back to `"No"` for the next value. As already provided, you can use `break` to exit the loop on the first match. Or you can use `next` to get the next matching value, if any, or `"No"` otherwise.

```
dico = {}
for i, v in enumerate(listo):
    dico[i] = next((x for x in mm if x in v), "No")
```

This way, you could even turn this into a dictionary comprehension.

```
dico = {i: next((x for x in mm if x in v), "No") for i, v in enumerate(listo)}
```

However, using `"No"` as a default is probably not a good choice, since it could technically also be in `mm`. Instead, you might rather use `None`.
But judging from comments you might actually want a list of *all* matches, which would be even simpler:

```
dico = {i: [x for x in mm if x in v] for i, v in enumerate(listo)}
# {0: ['med'], 1: [], 2: [], 3: ['holy'], 4: []}
```

Of course, if the key is just the index, you can also use an even simpler list comprehension:

```
dico = [[x for x in mm if x in v] for v in listo]
# [['med'], [], [], ['holy'], []]
```

(Also, you are testing `in` when the values are actually `==`, but this may be just in this example.)

Comment: can I use a list comprehension instead of a dict comprehension? if so how to do that.

Comment: thanks. However, what if I want a single output per index. In other words, I don't want to have a list per each output. something like:  ['med', , , 'holy', ]. because I've tried to delete the inner list comp [] and an error raised : local variable 'v' referenced before assignment

Comment: @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi Just do it with `next` than as in the first version, but as a list comprehension as in the third: `[next((x for x in mm if x in v), None) for v in listo]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to `break` from the loop if you find a match, and set it to `No` only if no matches were found. Like this:

```
dico = {}

listo = ['med', 'lam', 'rih', 'holy', 'lem']
mm = ['med', 'holy']
for i, v in enumerate(listo):
    for x in mm:
        if x in v:
            dico[i] = x
            break
    else:
        dico[i] = 'No'

print(dico)
```

Output:

```
{0: 'med', 1: 'No', 2: 'No', 3: 'holy', 4: 'No'}
```

The problem that you are having is that because you do not break from the inner `for` loop, you overwrite `dico[0]` with `'No'` on later iterations, after you already wrote `'med'`.

(Note indentation of the `else` here - it accompanies the `for` rather than the `if`.)

Comment: thanks, it works. please, how to set dico[i] = list(x), in case of multiple values are found?

Comment: If you want a list, then it would make more sense to use a list in all situations, including an empty list if no values were found, and a one-element list if one value is found. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, indeed. How to do that?

Comment: @Mohamed-IslemHachaichi You would initialise the list inside your outer `for` loop (e.g. `dico[i] = []`) then inside the `if` block you would do `dico[i].append(x)` (instead of `dico[i] = x`) and remove the `break` statement, and you would also remove the `else` block.